# How do I access the link to the content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How do I access the content of link to by JavaScript and jquery

```
 <a href='http://example.com' id='my id'>content</a>
```

Comment: You want the href? Please edit and clarify your question

Comment: $('#my_id').attr('href'); (id cant have space - replace it with _
next time - search

Comment: i would access to the content on alink
<a href='http://example.com' id='my id'>content</a>
on the above example i would access the content

Comment: This is *extremely* basic. Have you tried anything?

Comment: so do you want to display/get the contents from the link address of your anchor tags? if so then you can use iframe.

Comment: this code $ ("# mycredit"). attr ("href")
Get through it, but on the link,
I want to get the value of your text linkage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all the `id` cannot contain spaces.

Then with jQuery to access the `content` the value in the DOM you need to use the `.html()` after the selector.

Here is a working example : 
http://jsfiddle.net/zuz660uk/

If on the other end you want the value of `href` then use `.attr('href')`

Comment: tank you 
That's what I meant
But Can I access the value only without link

Comment: What do you mean by `without link`?